# Вывод максимальной даты

Tags: sql, oracle

Не могу вывести строчку с максимальной датой. строчки вообще перестают выводиться

```
select ff.*
from wi.xs$fd ff
   where ff.date_mod = (select max(ff.date_mod) from wi.xs$fd ff ) and
   doc_type like 'FD.ANKETA_PIT' 
   and status = 0
   and code = 37048
```

Скрины с примерами во вложениях. Помогите пожалуйста)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы уверены, что строка с максимальной датой у вас соответствует именно таким значениям полей, которые вы указали в `WHERE`? Для начала попробуйте убрать все остальные условия из `WHERE` кроме условия на дату. А дальше разбирайтесь, почему условия не срабатывают, включая их по одному.

Comment: Или наоборот, добавьте эти условия и в подзапрос.

Comment: @Akina Ну да, в зависимости от того, что собственно хочет автор вопроса - глобальный максимум, или условный

Comment: По моему во вложенном запросе Вам необходимо указать ! where !, то есть:
where ff.date_mod = (select max(f.date_mod) from wi.xs$fd f 
where f.doc_type = ff.doc_type
   and f.status = ff.status
   and f.code = ff.code  )